# Require at 4 checkboxes to be checked from the group

Tags: jquery, forms

I've created a user form. The user gets 10 options and he needs to choose four of them. Whenever I submit the form with less then 4 checkboxes selected and then select another, the validation message will appear unless I select and unselect all unchecked checkboxes.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[name^='opties']").change(function() {
    if ($("input[name^='opties']:checked").length < 4) {
      $("input[name^='opties']").prop('required', true);
    } else {
      $("input[name^='opties']").removeAttr('required');
    }
  });
});

<input type="checkbox" name="opties[<?echo $cell?>]" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Voer minstens 4 opties in')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" required>
```

Comment: Your logic seems fine, although could be optimised slightly. Is there a specific issue you have?

Comment: Yes, it works fine when 4 options are selected before submitting. But if i submit with less then 4 options, all other (say 7) checkboxes get the error message. Then I additionally select 1 (so the total is 4) but then the other 6 still have the error message (even when the 'required' property is deleted).

Comment: When i select and deselect all other 6 the problem is solved, but thats not something i want my users to do...

Comment: give your html code also...

Comment: I put it in the code, i use PHP to create 10 of those

Comment: give a single JQuery css error message in group fieldset,not push required to all checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Validation on the client side isn't critical but it's good UX. I prefer the use of `[required]` when convenient but it looks like this situation is too much of a headache. Try disabling the submit button until 4 checkboxes are checked and inform the user how many more options are required. When 4 or more are checked, enable the submit button and inform the user that they may submit the form.

```js
$(':checkbox').on("change", chx);

function chx(e) {
  var checked = $(':checkbox:checked').length;
  var remaining = 4 - checked;
  var message, send;
  if (remaining <= 0) {
    message = `Submit Options When Done`;
    send = false;
  } else {
    message = `Pick <b>${remaining}</b> or More Options`;
    send = true;
  }
  $('.chxMsg').html(message);
  $(':submit').prop('disabled', send);
}
```

```css
.chxMsg b {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <fieldset class='chxGrp'>
    <legend class='chxMsg'>Pick <b>4</b> or More Options</legend>
    <input name='opt' type='checkbox' value='0'>
    <input name='opt' type='checkbox' value='1'>
    <input name='opt' type='checkbox' value='2'>
    <input name='opt' type='checkbox' value='3'>
    <input name='opt' type='checkbox' value='4'>
    <input name='opt' type='checkbox' value='5'>
    <input name='opt' type='checkbox' value='6'>
    <input name='opt' type='checkbox' value='7'>
    <input name='opt' type='checkbox' value='8'>
    <input name='opt' type='checkbox' value='9'>
    <input type='submit' disabled>
  </fieldset>
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```